# Threading: Second thread is not running in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

All the topics I found didn't help me, so I decided to ask by myself. I need to start two different bots on parallel but only the first thread is running.

Here's my code:

```
threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(vkbot.run_forever(),)).start() #first bot
threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(bot.run(token=token),)).start() #second bot
```

I tried to use `multiprocessing` but I had the same problem - only the first process was running. When I swapped them nothing changed - only the first process was running again. What's the problem?

UPD: Full simplified code:

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
import threading, discord
from discord import commands

vkbot = Bot(token=vk_token)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=intents)

@vkbot.on.message()
async def main(message: Message):
    if message.text.lower().startswith("+reg"):
        await message.answer("something")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")

# Here are the methods I can't run in parallel
vkbot.run_forever() 
bot.run(token=token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've found out that `asyncio.run()` and threads don't mix.

Instead, `asyncio.run()` an [`asyncio.gather()` that will kick off the two coroutines as tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently):

```
asyncio.run(
    asyncio.gather(
        vkbot.run_polling(),  # The async coroutine vkbottle uses
        bot.run(token=token),
    )
)
```

Comment: Still only the first task is running :(

Comment: Then I'll assume `vkbot.run_forever()` is blocking, but since I don't know what it is, I can't help further.

Comment: If `vkbot.run_forever()` is blocking, why is discord bot (`bot.run()`) the only running when it is called before `vkbot.run_forever()` in `asyncio.gather()`?

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing the functions. Both _are_ `async`, right?

Comment: I updated my message and added simplified version of my code

Comment: Right - based on the source for vkbottle the async coroutine called by `run_forever` is `run_polling` - plug that into `asyncio.gather`.